# How do I copy part of a commit diff in GitHub without the pluses and the minuses?

Tags: git, github, version-control, diff, git-commit

It's very often that I need to copy-and-paste part of a GitHub commit. Whenever I do this, however, I find myself manually going down each line and hitting `Delete` to strip all of the +/- signs.

Is there a more convenient way to copy part of a GitHub commit to the clipboard?
Suggestions involving Chrome extensions/your personal projects are welcome.

Comment: This should not be an issue anymore: see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Update July 2018](https://blog.github.com/changelog/2018-07-31-unselectable-diff-markers/):

> ### Unselectable diff markers
>
> The `+` and `-` diff markers are **no longer copied to your clipboard when you copy the contents of a diff**.

Yay!

---

Original answer (August 2017)

You could:

- [curl the diff itself from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21903890/6309) (without cloning the all repo history):

  ```
  https://github.com/foo/bar/commit/${SHA}.patch
  ```
- [pipe it to a sed to remove the +/-](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28551750/6309):

  ```
  .... | sed -r "s/^([^-+ ]*)[-+ ]/\\1/" | less -r
  ```

Comment: but, but... I *want* the diff markers! Often I copy a diff from the terminal and paste it, with markers, into markdown doc, with the `diff` code fence tag, so it gets syntax highlighted (e.g. in green and red). I just tried to do this with a diff from github, found that I couldn't, had to *add* the markers manually, did a bit of googling and found that copy used to include the markers, but now doesn't - waaah! :)

Comment: @drkvogel So why not copy it from the patch URL I mentioned originally? (example: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/commit/01c50adf56430fdd98f903691ae41a83870801c0.patch): the +/- are there.

Comment: OK, that's a good workaround, thanks. Not obvious, though, unless you have seen this thread and followed your links (which I now have). Perhaps GitHub should show a link to the patch, even though it's as simple as adding `.patch` to the URL?

Comment: @drkvogel Agreed: that feature could benefit from more visibility in the UI.