# Hide the leading plus/minus in git log -p to easily copy the lost code

Tags: git

Sometimes I may look through the git log for some lost code only in commits.

eg: search some code like `XXX` using `git log -p -S XXX`, but the output may have leading +/-, I want to hide them to copy the code directly to my project, since the + code is green, - code is red, I can easily distinguish them.

Thanks for any other way to copy code from git log easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
git log -p -S XXX --color-words
```

As mentioned in "[Git: remove leading plus/minus from lines in diff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34175594/6309)" that would remove the `+/-`.

As [seen in `git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

> The command takes options applicable to the `git rev-list` command to control what is shown and how, **and options applicable to the `git diff-*` commands to control how the changes each commit introduces are shown.**